# Web scraping of an eCommerce website using Google Chrome extension

Tags: web-scraping

I am trying to do web scraping of an eCommerce website and have looked for all major kind of possible solutions.The best I found out is web scraping extension of Google Chrome. I actually want to pull out all data available in the website.

For example, I am trying to scrape data of an eCommerce site [www.bigbasket.com](http://www.bigbasket.com). Now while trying to create a site map , I am stuck to this part where I have to chose element from a page. Same page of say category A, while being scrolled down contains various products ,and one category page is further split as as page 1, page 2 and few categories have page 3 and so on as well.

Now if I am selecting multiple elements of same page say page 1 it's totally fine, but when I am trying to select element from page 2 or page 3, the scraper prompts with different type element section is disabled,and asks me to enable by selecting the checkbox, and after that I am able to select different elements. But when I run the site map and start scraping, scraper returns null values and data is not pulled out. I don't know how to overcome this problem so that I can draw a generalized site map and pull the data in one go.

Comment: I have looked for all possible sort of solutions.First I tried to pull data through selenium but stucked in the same situation where xPath for two rows were identical but diffrentiated by some random numbers.so I started looking for tool to get my work done.Please help me whosoever has worked uo pn this domain.Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

To prevent web scraping various websites now use rendering by JavaScript. The website (bigbasket.com), you're using also uses JS for rendering info to various elements. To scrape websites like these you will need to use Selenium instead of traditional methods (like beautifulsoup in Java).

You will also have to check various legal aspects of this and whether the website wants you crawling this data.

Comment: Thanks a lot. But I have mentioned that I am using selenium only. Also , I am not sure of the legal aspect of the website, but I was only trying to learn crawling and e-commerce was the best platform for POC.